# Htaccess broke $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a .htacess file like ;

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Let say I have a url : `www.example.com/index/action`. 
When I print `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` in index.php I see `/action`

But if my url is like `www.example.com/index1/action` I can see `/index1/action`

but i want to see the full path in both case. How can i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to see the URL before it is rewritten, I believe you are looking for:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

This helpful bit of code will insert the address of the page the user is currently on, so if you were on "http://test.com/pages/test/" the code would copy the "/pages/test/". To use it in the code:

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`.

For `www.example.com/index/action`, you'd get `/index.php/index/action`

For `www.example.com/index1/action`, you'd get `/index.php/index1/action`